# What is the difference between event and outcome in probability theory?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Mathematically, we have a probability space (X, Omega , P), and we say X is sample space, which contains all the "outcomes", and Omega is an sigma-algebra on X, containing all the "events". And last, P is a probability measure.
I can understand the difference between "outcome" and "event", since basically, an outcome is an "element", and "event" is a "set". But in application, what is the fundamental difference between an outcome and an event? Is it that we just define them without any specific reason, or there are some criteria?
Another concern is, by definition, it seems that we will almost in every case define the probability of any outcome(an event that contains only one certain outcome) to be the same number(we consider the discrete case here). Like, if there are 6 outcomes in total, we tend to define every outcome to have probability 1/6, though not necessarily mathematically I think. But intuitively, how we can say all outcomes have the same probability? 
For example, for a fair 4-face dice, we can define outcomes like this:{{1, 2}, 3, 4}. Intuitively, {1, 2} cannot be an outcome because we can further divide it into two outcomes {1} and {2}. But in real application problem, it is not always that intuitive, I think. Sometimes you do not know whether "an outcome" has been divided as possible as we can.

Comment: I explained in the problem that I already know it is legitimate, but it is just not intuitively right to do so. I used "we tend to" not "we must". And we always tend to do this, don't we? But the problem is, how intuition work here? You never know your intuition works well to make every outcome have the same probability.

Comment: Yes, your are right. I know the reason to make every outcome to be as "small" as possible. We do this in order to have "more" events. Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I agree with your assumptions about people's intuition. That seems like a psychology issue, not a math problem. However, your question about the distinction between a sample point and an event is a mathematical question.

Let's take a simple probability space (below $P$ is a probability measure) :

$$\Omega:=\{1,2,3\}\;\;\mathcal{F}:=\{\{1,2\},\{\emptyset\},\{1,2,3\},\{3\}\}\;\;P: \mathcal{F} \to[0,1]$$

Note that our $\sigma-$field does not contain all the singletons of $\Omega$. Therefore, one way to make the distinction here is that events are subsets of  $\Omega$ that we can logically attach probabilities to given the choice of measure $P$.

If we grant intuitive primacy to the $\sigma-$field, then we can define $\Omega$ as the union of all the sets in $\mathcal{F}$.

In many practical cases, the sample points are valid events too, its just that they are singleton events.

Comment: For example, when we learned probably theory, we often did homework like this:"if we have two coins, and we flip them at the same moment. What's the probability we get one head and one tail?" The answer is definitely 1/4. But someone who do not have very good sense of mathematics would say,"you see, you can only get three outcomes, two heads, two tails, one head and one tail. So the probability is 1/3!" Why he is wrong here? I might say, because "one head and one tail" can be divided into two different outcomes "1st is head, 2nd is tail" and the inverse. But it's only intuition, isn't it?

Comment: What's the reason to have four different outcomes here instead of three. If you do experiment, apparently four outcomes would agree with the experiment results.

Comment: @EdwardWang no, you need 4 outcomes since your sample space is $\{H,T\}^2$ so its demonstrably wrong.

Comment: We can legitimately define the sample space to be {(H,H), (T,T), {(H,T),(T,H)}}. There is nothing wrong mathematically. But when we define the probability measure, the problem comes. How do we know a head and a tail has probability 1/2? By the answers above, we only need to satisfy the probability axioms to be mathematically right. But we have no rules to assign the probability to meet the experiment results.

Comment: I think my problem should be: in mathematics, a measure only need to satisfy those axioms to be a probability measure. But in reality, we cannot just randomly grasp a probability measure that just meets the axioms, because experiments are real, experiments don't lie. There should be some other rules. So what are the other rules?

Comment: @EdwardWang you've just described the difference between mathematics and modeling. In physics, not just any second order diffeq would describe classical mechanics. Same with probability: not just any measure will match experiment.

Comment: OK I understand. Thus the axioms actually avoid the reality problem .I guess psychology has some effects here. I really don't know. It's completely understandable to treat symmetrical results with a same probability.

Comment: @EdwardWang well, when we have no information to favor one outcome to another, we often default to equiprobable outcomes...doesn't mean its right, but it's what we do sometimes...

Comment: So you mean in the case above, we have extra information to treat one head one tail to have probability 1/2. Am I right? But what if we cannot find any extra info, and no one can, then people just get consensus on the probability? No one can find still doesn't mean there isn't any extra info.

Comment: @EdwardWang I suggest you look up the different interpretations of probability (see Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy). How you decide on a probability is determined by what you think probability means. I'll leave it at that for this post.

Answer (score 4):

In a real application, you want to make sure that an outcome includes all aspects of the result of the experiment that you might be interested in, and that every possible result of the experiment is covered. Beyond that, you have a lot of freedom. You usually do not want to clutter things up by including details that don't matter to you, unless having them there makes it easier to calculate probabilities.  Thus for the die, even though the difference between 1 and 2 might not make a difference to you, you will count them as separate outcomes to make counting easier using symmetry.

A less artificial example is when you roll several fair dice.  You want to distinguish between outcomes "1 on the first die and 2 on the second" and 
"2 on the first die and 1 on the second", even if you don't care which is which, because this makes outcomes equally likely.

EDIT:  Maybe I should also say something about $\sigma$-fields that do not contain singletons.  At first this may seem rather artificial.  But such things turn out to be quite useful when considering experiments that take place in stages.

For example, let's say your experiment consists of an infinite sequence of coin-tosses.  The outcomes consist of all infinite sequences of Heads and Tails.  But at a particular time $t$, you only know the results of the first $t$ tosses.  You thus might define a $\sigma$-field $\mathcal F_t$ for the
events that depend only on those first $t$ tosses.   An example of a member of $\mathcal F_3$ would be the set of outcomes with Heads on the first toss and Tails on the second.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I think one explanation here for why we always have the intuition to make every single outcome to have the same probability here is because of symmetry. But maybe how intuition deals with symmetry is what mathematics cannot answer.

Comment: Symmetry is good when you have it.  But that does not require all outcomes to have the same probability.  We can and do consider unfair dice and coins, it's just a little bit more complicated.